# ExcelDNA pass excel cell value displalys unexpected output

Tags: excel-dna

I use a function 
       public static object getContent(String keyword, object StartTime, object EndTime)
        {
            alert(StartTime);
        }

set cell A1 to 18-07-2012.And when calling =getContent("africa",A1,"04-09-2012")
dispalys 41108.what it means?Why its not taking value in A1!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has no built-in date/time data type. In Excel, date/times are formatting options for the double data type. You can declare an Excel-DNA function as taking a `DateTime` parameter to have the passed-in doubles converted to `DateTime` automatically, or you can do the conversion yourself using `DateTime.FromOADate()` (since the Excel double encoding matches the COM/OLE date implementation).

Comment: Thanks for the help.I tried DateTime.FronOADate() but got the same output as 41108.Sadly I need to use object datatype because sometimes it should accept a string value rather than TODAY() .Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: If you call DateTime.FromOAData(41108) you get a DateTime (2012/07/18 00:00:00). If you return this value to Excel and format the cell as a Date/Time, Excel will display the corresponding date.